# Debug WeChat OAuth2 in localhost testing environment

Tags: wechat-miniprogram, wechat-auth

I would like to implement a web application for a company in China. I need to use `WeChat mini-APP` to make the sign-up/login straight-forward.

Please correct my assumptions if I am wrong:

- To implement the login of the website from `WeChat`, I **need** to use the `OAuth2` protocol
- I also need to create a `WeChat developer account` under a real name (need ID card or business registration stuff) if I want to diffuse the application
- I also need to register a `domain name` to `WeChat` so that they can allow `OAuth2 authentication` to this domain name

Question: can I still use my `localhost virtual machine` to develop my server?
(I didn't try but I assume WeChat will reject to create an `OAuth2 token` for `localhost 127.0.0.1`)

Or do I need to have a development domain name with a development server available from the Internet so that I can debug the OAuth2 authentication?

EDIT 1: I tried to send a HTTPS POST request `https://127.0.0.1:8080` and I got an error linking to this URL
https://developers.weixin.qq.com/miniprogram/dev/framework/ability/network.html

EDIT 2: I tried to send a HTTPS POST request `https://192.168.1.148:8080` which correspond to my dev computer and I got the error `VM17415:1 Cannot send network request to localhost.` (My test phone and computer both connected to network 192.168.1.x trough WiFi)

Comment: Many trouble wait you.For what I can tell mini-app doesn't need to auth 2.0.It has special authorization mode.It needs support from server-side.But server-side auth needs configiure trusted doname.So it may not test localhost unless setting a proxy from server-side online to your localhost virtual machine.If you don't consider progress of authorization,to test your business code on your localhost virtual machine is avaliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is available in English on the official WebSite [1]. It is written: `network APIs allow communication with LAN IP addresses`. So basically, if the phone is connected to the same network as the virtual machine (i.e. WiFi), one should be able to send any kind of HTTP/HTTPS request properly.

Note that the development environment **WeChat DevTools block this feature by default**. In order to enable it, the user should open the `Project Settings` and `check the box` *'Does not verify valid domain names, web-view (business domain names), TLS versions and HTTPS certificates.'*.

[1] https://developers.weixin.qq.com/miniprogram/en/dev/framework/ability/network.html